# convert a php array with key in a string?

Tags: arrays, implode

I am novice in php development and I need your help.

I have read the column of a file and I want to keep in an array
only the distinct values

I do it with this code in a while (fgetcsv) loop

```
$sex_array = array();
isset($sex_array[$sex])?$sex_array[$sex]++:$sex_array[$sex]=1;
```

my array is in format 
Array ( [man] => 33 [woman] => 141 )

How can I make a variable and when I print it to take 
man:33,woman:141

I tried implode but I take 33,141

Answer (score 0):

look at [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) taken from the page:

```
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    echo "\$a[$k] => $v.\n";
}
```